# What is the difference between "behavior" and "behaviour"?

Tags: american-english

In [the online version of Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/), there are these definitions for the next two words:

> Behaviour = the way that someone behaves
>
> Behavior = a particular way of acting

What would be a difference between *behavior* and *behaviour* by some example?

Comment: Related pages comparing the two: [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/spelling/behavior-behaviour/), [Grammar.com](https://www.grammar.com/behavior_vs._behaviour), [Writing Explained](https://writingexplained.org/behavior-or-behaviour-difference) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior) (which only briefly notes both versions). I found these by Googling "behavior and behaviour".

Comment: If you look at the 2 definitions, you will see that they come from different sources; this is why the definitions differ in their wording.

Comment: I am not sure as I am not up to date with rules being followed here, but this seems like a very basic question to start with and should not be allowed in this forum. And if it has to be, it sets a bad example for more such questions to be asked in future.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

They mean the same thing; behaviour is the British English spelling; behavior is the American spelling. The definitions say the same thing in different ways.

Comment: It should be noted that this is very common - there are many words which end in "our" in British English and "or" in American English.

Comment: Right, Darrel, and I'd like to add that the words ‘motor’, ‘rotor’, ‘abhor’ are not among them. :)

Comment: @ArtyomLugovoy you are coming at it from the other way.  Look first for the 'our' words in BE then their corresponding word in AmE.

Comment: @mcalex I just mentioned that if one sees an 'or' word, that doesn't necessarily mean there is a corresponding 'our' word. As well as the words ‘pour’ and ‘sour’ existing in BrE are the same in AmE.

Answer (score 62):

In fact, there is no difference between *behaviour* and *behavior* except spelling. The former is preferred in British and Commonwealth English, the latter is the American spelling.

The entries are confusing because there is no single "Cambridge Dictionary." Cambridge University Press actually publishes dozens of different dictionaries. Their website, however, searches them all at once, and returns definitions which may or may not be relevant to you.

When you look up *[behaviour](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/behaviour)*, you are given entries from the *Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus* and the *Cambridge Business English Dictionary*. When you look up *[behavior](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/behavior)*, you are given the entry in the *Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary*, and from the *Cambridge Business English Dictionary* a pointer to the entry for *behaviour*. Because the target audience for each dictionary is different, you see slightly different entries, but this is a quirk of the *Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary* failing to synonymize the spellings.

I commend you for doing your best with references, but would also recommend you limit searches to a learner's dictionary (e.g. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/), [Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/), [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/), or [Merriam-Webster](http://learnersdictionary.com/)) to avoid this happening in the future.

Comment: your Cambridge there is no IPA for US and because I stay with my Cambridge. Thank a lot for your excellent explanation to me.

Comment: All the learner's dictionaries listed above, except _Macmillan_, give IPA pronunciations for both US and UK.  The _Cambridge Learner's_ shows both pronunciations if they are [different](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/garage), but only shows only a single one if they are the same.

Answer (score 12):

In short, they're the same word spelt differently in the US and the UK.

---

It's not very obvious because of the way Cambridge has laid out their pages.

> #### [behaviour](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/behaviour)
>
> noun UK **US behavior**

> #### [behavior](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/behavior)
>
> noun [ C/U ] CDN **BR behaviour**
>
> #### behavior
>
> noun [ U ]
>
> →  behaviour

---

Wiktionary's entries are much clearer:

> ### [behaviour](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/behaviour)
>
> #### Alternative forms
>
> behavior (US)

> ### [behavior](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/behavior)
>
> #### Alternative forms
>
> behaviour (UK)

Answer (score -1):

*Behaviour* is the British spelling and *behavior* is the American variant.

The British spelling is in this case slightly more faithful to the etymology of the word.

The OED has the following etymology of *behaviour*:

> - formed on the verb *behave*, by form-analogy with *havour*, *havyoure*, common 15–16th century forms of the word which was originally the noun *aver* (q.v.), *aveyr*, also in 15th century *avoir*; really Old French *aveir*, *avoir*, in sense of ‘having, possession,’ but naturally affiliated in English to the native verb *have*, and spelt *haver*, *havour*, *haviour*, etc. Hence, by analogy, *have*: *havour*, *-iour*: *behave*: *behavour*, *-iour*.
> - The formation might be confirmed by the (apparently) parallel *demeanour*, from *demean* (oneself). For the *-iour* see *havour*.

The etymology of *havour*:

> - Originally an adoption of the French *aveir*, *avoir* ‘having, possession, property, estate, wealth, etc.’, substantive use of *avoir*, Old French *aveir* ‘to have’.
> - First used in English in the Norman form *aveyr* [...]; the Central French form *avoir* appeared about 1400, and displaced *aver*, except in the northern dialect, where that form survived in a specific sense.
> - In 14–15th century, association with the English *have*, *having*, introduced the variants *haver*, *havoir*, *havour*, and the *h* was established before 1500. At the same time the parallel *behavour* was formed on the English *behave*; and in 16th century *havour*, beside its original sense of ‘possession’, took also that of *behavour*.
> - Subsequently the termination of both words passed through *-eour* to *-iour* (cf. *saviour*, and vulgar ‘*lovier*’); the original sense ‘possession’ became obsolete; and, in the new sense, *haviour* came down alongside of *behaviour*, of which it may often have been viewed as a shortened by-form.

The American spelling, *behavior*, on the other hand, is effectively more 'phonetic' in nature, in that it dispenses with the *u* (there are only a few exceptions), which is otherwise not pronounced. At the beginning of the 19th century, Noah Webster pushed this change primarily via his dictionary, and Americans gradually adopted the new spelling. [Etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-or) says:

> When the Americans began to consistently spell it one way, however, the British reflexively hardened their insistence on the other. "The American abolition of *-our* in such words as *honour* and *favour* has probably retarded rather than quickened English progress in the same direction." [Fowler]

---

If you're using American English, you should write *behavior*. If, on the other hand, you're using the British variant, write *behaviour*. The important thing is to be be consistent, as the commenters say: it'd be considered unusual to have both *colo**u**r* and *behavior* in the same sentence.

In short: pick a dialect and use it consistently.

Comment: This is very much not correct. I don't really know where to start, but there is literally no sense in which British English is 'more correct' than any other form of English. Likewise, many American words and phrases are older than the British English equivalents, and were preserved by the separation of North American and British populations. Furthermore, 'color' et al were common spellings before the standardization of spelling in Britain, and '-ize' has only recently become something Britons generally avoid. '-ize' and '-ise' are still both acceptable in British English.

Comment: It is far more important that someone be consistent in their choice of English variation than to choose one particular one over the other. If I see “colour” I expect that the grammar and vocabulary will be British. If the subsequent text uses American grammar or vocabulary, then I will view it as a mistake, where I wouldn’t if the “color” spelling were used. Students should learn whichever variation they have the best access to native speakers of.

Comment: @fred2 Apologies, I didn't mean to stir sentiment. I'm not implying 'British' English is somehow more noble. It's simply a matter of definition. 'English' is the language of England. Not to mention, within England there's a lot of regional dialects too, so the canonical version of English is that known as 'The Queen's tongue', which is what most people mean by 'British' English. Older origins are not relevant. I'm from Cyprus, which is closer to ancient Greek than modern Greek. But I would never claim the Cypriot dialect is canonical for that reason. Greek is the language spoken in Greece.

Comment: Similarly, if Americans decided to claim their language by the name Americanese, and call English "British Americanese", then Americanese would be the canonical language in America, and a variant in Britain. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou This answer, along with the corresponding comments, shows a profound ignorance of how the English language developed, and what a language is. In linguistics (a field you evidently have no experience in) there's a distinction between British English (BrE) and American English (AmE) as two families of dialects which implement what linguists call Standard English. Not all dialects implement Standard English, but those that we call BrE and AmE do.

Comment: @userr2684291 I take your point (minus the ad hominem), but there's some misunderstanding here. You're making a point on standardization, whereas I'm suggesting that British English be the canonical reference standard for learners. I did not suggest lack of standardisation for American English as my reason. W.r.t. English language _learning_, especially as a Foreign Language, I would consider English as spoken in England to be the de-facto canonical language reference, and American English to be a variant in that respect. But, I agree my answer as written isn't clear and has managed to upset.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou "In any case, the canonical 'British' spelling [...] is typically **the more 'correct' one in a linguistic sense**" – this is absolutely incorrect. Do you understand that? You're suggesting that BrE be used as some sort of canonical English, and you base that suggestion on false claims such as the above.

Comment: "One is the canonical (i.e. so-called "British") spelling and the other is the (idiomatic) American variant. Note that, in a linguistic sense, there is no such thing as "British" English, anymore than there is "Italian" Italian, [...] etc. "British" English represents the canonical form of the language, and American English represents a 'topical' (albeit internationally exposed through modern technology) idiomatic variant, in a similar way that Latin American Spanish is a variant of the canonical form of Spanish that is spoken in Spain, [...], etc." – this is all incorrect.

Comment: @userr2684291 Thank you. I'm happy for you to edit as appropriate to make it a better / less offensive answer. The point about 'correct' however is referring specifically to the point I'm making about favouring preservation of etymology over phonetic representation in loanwords etc, e.g. "oesophagus vs esophagus, haem vs heme, centre vs center" etc; this is a characteristic distinction between the two variants. I suppose 'correct' is a bad word as it can be taken in a subjective way. 'More faithful' perhaps?

Comment: @userr2684291, your edit practically removed the original answer and posted a new one. As much as I may disagree with the original answer, this is not the way to treat it. You should provide your own answer (which may get its own votes) and keep the old one out there (other people may downvote it).

Comment: @laugh I tried to stay as faithful as possible to the spirit of the intended answer as expanded in the comments with the answerer's express permission to edit it. I don't normally deal with such answers that way, but I appreciate your concern.

Comment: Well, it's a reasonably good answer now, but you won't get any credit from votes on it...

Comment: @userr2684291: laugh is right, please feel free to copy it as a separate personal answer since this question is still getting traction. Let me know if you do this and I can revert or delete my previous answer. Having said that, I often find great value in controversial-and-subsequently-edited answers, where much of the value lies in the discussion itself. (e.g. I often find wikipedia talk pages much more informative than the article pages themselves). In any case, while I still disagree with some of the discussion, I admit I learned something new myself here, so I still find it useful.